# Apenas ler o primeiro caractere de uma string

Tags: php

```
if ($myrow['Noticia'] !== '<' && $myrow['Noticia'] !== 'Nao') {
   echo "Noticia mal colocada!";
}
```

Tenho esse código e gostaria que apenas fosse checar o primeiro caractere da coluna `Noticias` que seria este `<` e se não tivesse este caractere no início, e fosse diferente de *Nao* , apresentava a mensagem.

Comment: podes juntar o(s) exemplo(s) de string(s) correta(s)?

Comment: $myrow apenas vai buscar as colunas da minha tabela, nada mais..

Comment: mas se queres comparar/analizar `$myrow['Noticia']` estás a comparar/analizar uma string, certo? a minha pergunta é: que valores corretos pode `$myrow['Noticia']` ter dentro que queres verificar. Dá exemplo(s) de casos certos e errados para percebermos melhor o problema...

Comment: desculpe, mas nao estou a perceber a sua pergunta/questao :s

Comment: O que eu queria era que o PHP apenas checkasse se na coluna está `<` ou nao .. se nao tiver aparece uma mensagem ..

Comment: Então queres verificar se a string começa com `<` certo? e para além disso queres verificar se é diferente de "Não". Certo?

Comment: Certo, isso mesmo amigo!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você pode ler o primeiro caractere passando o índice dele, como se fosse uma array:

```
$myrow['Noticia'][0]
```

Nota: o `$myrow['Noticia'][0]` vai gerar um aviso (*notice*) se o valor da string for nulo.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou, pode esclarecer-me mais sobre o `[0]`?

Comment: `[0]` diz que você vai pegar o caractere que está na posição zero da string (o primeiro caractere). `[1]` pega o segundo, e assim por diante.

Comment: e por exemplo, e se quiser pegar nos primeiros dois ou no primeiro e o terceiro?

Comment: O primeiro e o terceiro você precisaria pegar separadamente. Se quiser pegar mais de um em sequência, use uma função própria para isso como `substr`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php

Answer (score 6):

Uma outra alternativa é a função [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php):

```
if (substr($myrow['Noticia'], 0, 1) !== '<' && $myrow['Noticia'] !== 'Nao') {
   echo "Noticia mal colocada!";
}
```

Onde `substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`:

- `$string`: A variável que será analisada.
- `$start`: Indica a posição inicial em `$string`.
- `$length`: A quantidade de caracteres que deve ser retornado a partir de `$start`.